# Open workspace when testing VS Code extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, testing, vscode-extensions

I am writing a test suite for my VS Code extension using [`vscode-extension-tester`](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-extension-tester/), and my tests need to involve the opening of a workspace file. I need the workspace file to be opened as soon as the browser is launched, in order for my subsequent tests to pass.

I am able to open the workspace file as a separate test; however, I was wondering if there's any setting that allows the workspace to be opened before any test is launched. Is there a way to do this with `vscode-extension-tester`?

Answer (score 2):

The way I handle this is through my launch configuration (launch.json).

Using an `extensionHost` type launch configuration you can pass a workspace file. This means that the code instance will open with the given workspace active whenever you execute it.

For example:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Run Extension",
            "type": "extensionHost",
            "request": "launch",
            "args": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/src/test/workspace/workspace.code-workspace",
                "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}"
            ],
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/*.js"
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "${defaultBuildTask}"
        },
        {
            "name": "Extension Tests",
            "type": "extensionHost",
            "request": "launch",
            "args": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/src/test/workspace/workspace.code-workspace",
                "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}",
                "--extensionTestsPath=${workspaceFolder}/out/test/suite/index"
            ],
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/out/**/*.js",
                "${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/*.js"
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "tasks: watch-tests"
        }
    ]
}
```

Note the path to `workspace.code-workspace` that is specified as an arg to both of these launch configs.

You will likely already have launch configs like this for running and testing your extension if you used [Yo Code](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-code) to generate your extension at the start of development.

So in summary:

1. Create your workspace
2. Store the workspace file accordingly (for me it made sense to be within `./src/test`)
3. Configure `extensionHost` type launch configs with a path to the workspace file given as an arg in the `args` array.